# ActionSherlockBar Styling - PopupMenu

Tags: java, android, styles, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Styling is a place for improvement in my knowledge of the android platform. Given I've being trying to make a simple change all morning and been unable to achieve it.

I want to change the style of the overflow menu in the action bar. I have been able to change the background color, and add animations, so that when clicked it fades to a selected colour. But for the life of me I cannot change the text colour.

Below are two screenshots, one using the Theme.Sherlock and the other using Theme.Sherlock.Light.

**Theme.Sherlock** - This is my current setting which I have customised. What I want is the overflow (aka android:popupmenu) to be in the holo theme (as below), and ideally so that I can change the text colour.

[image: Theme.Sherlock]

**Theme.Sherlock.Light** - This theme shows the style of overflow menu that I want to see. However, as highlighted in red, the overflow button is the wrong colour, and this theme also draws a horizontal line.

[image: Theme.Sherlock.Light]

I don't know whether it is best/easier to change Theme.Sherlock with the popup issue, or Theme.Sherlock.Light with the overflow icon and line issue. The application is of a "Light" theme so option two is probably the long term better choice, however i'll accept an answer that can solve the problem by changing either theme.

p.s. Where do you find a list of attributes for changing theme/styles, auto-complete is very incomplete in eclipse.

**Update**

This is actually an update for native action bars as im back to the same problem, but no longer supporting 2.3 or below.

```html
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
  <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
</style>

<style name="OverFlow" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.Overflow">
  <item name="android:src">**Insert your icon here**</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is probably coming too late, but to those who may stumble across this question.  I find it interesting that you were able to change the overflow's background color. I found that extremely difficult to figure out whereas changing the text was pretty straight forward.  Just override the `android:itemTextAppearance` value in your custom theme.

```xml
<item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/your_new_text_appearance</item>

<style name="your_new_text_appearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

Comment: We never did find a solution. But I have since moved onto a different company. I'll put your answer forward next time I see the other developers.

Comment: oh my god, I cannot upvote this enough. Two days trying dozens of ways to change that color, and finally a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with ActionBarSherlock, but you can find the standard OverFlow icons on your harddisk in the folder

```
path\to\android\android-sdk\platforms\android-api-level\data\res\drawable-resolution
```

and they are called `ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_dark.png`and `ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_light.png`

Alternatively you can find them online [here](http://androiddrawables.com/menu.html).

I believe that the left circle is a drawable, too. Look inside the `res\drawable`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Given a theme can make this possible, I would prefer to do that, than add another drawable image to the project. Just still trying to work out how to do it

Comment: Replying to this 2 years later and back in Android, im back to the same thing in native actionbars. Your spot on with the icons, but now I understand styling a little more. Just add to your style what I have added to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Simple do the following:

**1**. In the theme.xml in your app theme style add this item:

```
<item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
```

**2**. In styles.xml add this new style:

```
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListPopupWindow">
   <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

In the style you may override text size or other parameters as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try to override style of Theme.Sherlock with help of [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&backColor=E4E4E4,100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6,100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2,100&accentColor=33B5E5,100)